# Split pandas entry into all single characters and convert it to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have imported a txt file into a panda dataframe and the result is as shown below:

```
0   0101110011110110111001010100001111100010010010...
    Name: 0, dtype: object
```

I want to split that entry into all its individual numbers, and turn into a data frame where each row is each single element of the entry above:

The dataframe shall look like this:

```
0    0 \\

1    1 \\

2    0 \\

3    1 \\

4    1 \\

5    1 \\

6    0 \\

7    0 \\
....
```

Note: `0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7` are the row indexes.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: try splitting it with list("yourstringhere")

Comment: Can you show us your text file and the code that imports your dataframe? I think you can fix this at the source, instead of transforming the malformed df.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using pandas you can proceed as follows:

```
pd.DataFrame(df[0].apply(list)[0])
```

What this does is:

- convert the string 010111....0010 to a list of characters [0,1,0..0,1,0]
- use the resulting list to create a new dataframe with the format you are looking for.

---

Reproducible example:

```
In [26]: df = pd.DataFrame(['0101110011110110111001010100001111100010010010'])

In [27]: df
Out[27]: 
                                                0
0  0101110011110110111001010100001111100010010010

In [28]: pd.DataFrame(df[0].apply(list)[0]).head(10)
Out[28]: 
   0
0  0
1  1
2  0
3  1
4  1
5  1
6  0
7  0
8  1
9  1

In [29]:
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try to import the file correctly directly, instead of creating a dataframe with the wrong format first. Since pandas is built upon numpy, you could also use:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.array(list('0101110011110110111001010100001111100010010010'))
array(['0', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0',
       '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1',
       '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1',
       '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0'], 
      dtype='<U1')
```

If all the characters are either `'0'` or `'1'`, you could define a boolean array:

```
>>> a = np.array(list('0101110011110110111001010100001111100010010010'))
>>> a == '1'
array([False,  True, False,  True,  True,  True, False, False,  True,
        True,  True,  True, False,  True,  True, False,  True,  True,
        True, False, False,  True, False,  True, False,  True, False,
       False, False, False,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True, False,
       False, False,  True, False, False,  True, False, False,  True, False], dtype=bool)
```

You can then define a `DataFrame` based on this array:

```
>>> pd.DataFrame(a == '1')
        0
0   False
1    True
2   False
3    True
4    True
5    True
6   False
7   False
8    True
9    True
10   True
11   True
12  False
...
```

You didn't lose any information, but the resulting objects should take less space and be faster to process.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `list` to split

```
pd.DataFrame(list(df[0].item()))
```

or,

```
pd.DataFrame(list(df[0].iloc[0]))
```

Example

```
In [3526]: pd.DataFrame(list(df[0].item())).head(10)
Out[3526]:
   0
0  0
1  1
2  0
3  1
4  1
5  1
6  0
7  0
8  1
9  1
```

Details

```
In [3527]: df
Out[3527]:
                                                0
0  0101110011110110111001010100001111100010010010
```